# how to work with HTML5 at Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, html

> what is the best method to work with **HTML5**  at **Android** is i can only call the HTML5 files ? or i can have the call **HTML** codes at the Java page. Note i need to make more functions at **HTML** as the **HTML** have **JQuery** calender and I need to do more functions on this **calender**  .

> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

```
     WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

     wv = new WebView(this); 
     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );
     { 
         setContentView(wv); 
     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

     }



}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to mix native Android stuff and HTML-5 stuff (in a WebView) and want to know how you can inter-link both of them?

Comment: I think you may want something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) if you want to develop for Android using HTML5.

Comment: As Ali recommends, if you want to work with HTML-5 and need further features that plain HTML-5 does not provide, you could go with Phonegap or the like. This also has the advantage that you could make your apps for Android _and_ iOS etc.